# How can I stop a terminal connection from timing out

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal, putty, timeout

At work I have two machines: Windows XP and Ubuntu 11.04.

On my XP machine I use Putty to connect to some servers and can leave those windows open for weekends without them timing out.

However, when I connect tot the same serves from my Ubuntu box with Terminal, my connection times out before I even return from lunch or a meeting.

Is this by design or is there a setting i am missing?

Comment: Do you have the Ubuntu machine set to automatically suspend after a period of inactivity?  I recently ran into this problem with my new Windows 7 machine at work since it defaults to suspend after like half an hour, so when I got back from lunch and woke it up, the ssh connection was reset.

Comment: It wasn't a sleep/suspend issue in this particular case.  The only thing to occur is the screen saver turning on after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same issue with two Ubuntu boxes. There are settings in /etc/ssh/ssh_config that you can play with if you have root access, otherwise in your home folder .ssh/config try adding:
`Host *`
`ServerAliveInterval 500`
Otherwise there is a tool called "autossh" which will automatically reconnect on disconnect. You'll need to exchange keys if you want it to be fully automatic - and your session could get screwed up if you aren't using something like byobu or screen.